# URL pattern or REGEX for HTML5 url input element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, regex, html, url

What is the URL pattern that is being used with the HTML5 element input type="url". I tried some regex from various forums but felt HTML5 url element is having a different pattern of regex. Can someone crack the regex for it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing it's an RFC 3987 compliant regular expression, something like [***this***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url#answer-190405)

Comment: Can you suggest me an equivalent regex for input type="url" ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What regular expression does a browsers use for HTML5 input type=url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626293/what-regular-expression-does-a-browsers-use-for-html5-input-type-url)

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to get an equivalent regex for type="url" element.

```
/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/(([a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]+)|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]?)){3}(:?[0-9]*)))?(\/.*)?$/ix
```